# Adding new row at the top of the cell in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hey all i have a program for inserting new now dynamically in table view. But it displays the inserted row the end.How can i display the inserted row at the first position.

Comment: how did you implement insertion at the moment? seeing your code will help to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I will have an array to keep the data and each cell in the table view will correspond to an element in an array. If you have a NSMutableArray and you add the element at the beginning of the array and reload data, it should work properly. Or you can create a new array and add the new element at the first element and copy all old elements into the new one

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, please press the ✔ next to it.